# Why does we need access modifier "static" for some methods like the following one?

Tags: java, class, oop

Here is the code I got from the book "Java: The complete reference" by Herbert Schildt on page 239, 240 as PDF. I have researched about "static" but in this case, I wonder why static must be used.

```
import java.util.Random;

interface SharedConstants {
    int NO = 0;
    int YES = 1;
    int LATER = 3;
    int SOON = 4;
    int NEVER = 5;
}

class Question implements SharedConstants {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int ask() {
        int prob = (int) (100 * rand.nextDouble());
        if(prob < 30) return NO;
        else if(prob < 60) return YES;
        else if(prob < 75) return LATER;
        else if(prob < 98) return SOON;
        else return NEVER;
    }
}

public class AskMe implements SharedConstants {
    static void answer(int result) {
        switch(result) {
            case NO:
                System.out.println("No");
                break;
            case YES:
                System.out.println("Yes");
                break;
            case LATER:
                System.out.println("Later");
                break;
            case SOON:
                System.out.println("Soon");
                break;
            case NEVER:
                System.out.println("Never");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Question q = new Question();
        answer(q.ask());
        answer(q.ask());
        answer(q.ask());
        answer(q.ask());
    }
}
```

I wonder at the line that created `answer` method in class `AskMe`. Why do we need the "static" access control? If not, the compiler will give error like "error: non-static method answer(int) cannot be referenced from a static context".

Thanks in advance.

(This is my first time asking question, if any mistakes, tell me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **could**, but without `static` you would need an instance of `AskMe` to call `answer` in `main`. Like,

```
void answer(int result) {
    switch(result) {
        case NO:
            System.out.println("No");
            break;
        case YES:
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        case LATER:
            System.out.println("Later");
            break;
        case SOON:
            System.out.println("Soon");
            break;
        case NEVER:
            System.out.println("Never");
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question q = new Question();
    AskMe askMe = new AskMe();
    askMe.answer(q.ask());
    askMe.answer(q.ask());
    askMe.answer(q.ask());
    askMe.answer(q.ask());
}
```

Comment: Thank @Elliott, but can you tell me is it better to use `static` or use the instance of `AskMe` in this case ? And why ?

Comment: @HoangNguyen They're roughly equivalent. Consider, you could pass a `Question` to the `AskMe` constructor and let `answer` call `ask` directly. But this is a trivial example; real code is seldom so clear cut.

Comment: @HoangNguyen The primary real-world problem is with static variables (there are many viewpoints regarding static methods); constants (`static final`) are okay, but avoid static variables because they create a hidden link between different parts of your program.

Comment: @HoangNguyen You're welcome. I notice you have yet to take the complimentary (that means free) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/), you should do so.

Comment: Let me see, i'm new!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I search but haven't yet known to take the complimentary, i mean the tour. I just go to tour but don't what to do.

Comment: @HoangNguyen **Read** it. That is all. I see you did.